# Problem with OpenThread build procedure - src/<name.c> file is not included

Tags: nrf52, openthread

I have some problem with build procedure, i.e. after adding new file in `openthread/examples/platforms/nrf528xx/nrf52840/Makefile.am` in the section `PLATFORM_COMMON_SOURCES`, this added file is not build during compilation.

I have followed this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/openthread-apis/#3

I stuck in this point. I cannot figure out how to make it working...

Best regards!

Comment: Issue has been solved by myself...
**REMEMBER**: if you add something to `Makefile.am` file, before build you must run `./bootstrap`...

Comment: If you did solve the problem, you can make this your answer and post more details in your answer than in a comment.  This will be good for documentation of your issue.  As a bonus, you can then give yourself points, which is not against the rules here.

Comment: @DougF 
Thanks for information :) I will adjust to it :)

Comment: Your welcome.  Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer by clicking the checkmark so you get your points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make any change to `Makefile.am` file, you must run `./bootstrap` before compilation. If you don't, any change will be not included in the build process.

Additionally, always clean `build` directory to be sure that everything will be compiled as you wish.